# Performing an action ONCE after a delay of n seconds, WP7 C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm looking for a simple way to perform an action/method after a delay of n seconds. The thing I found a few examples but they seem overly complex for when on my last platform, iOS, it was just

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withDelay:3];
```

Any tips or code snippets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `Scheduler.Dispatcher` from `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive`:

```
Scheduler.Dispatcher.Schedule(MethodName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

private void MethodName()
{
    // This happens 5 seconds later (on the UI thread)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DispatcherTimer DelayedTimer = new DispatcherTimer()
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};
DelayedTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    //perform action
    DelayedTimer.Stop();
}
DelayedTimer.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Windows Phone 8` you can use

```
await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            // do some very quick work here

            // update the UI
            StatusText.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        };

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Start();
```

Note that what you're doing here is interrupting the UI thread, not really running anything on a separate thread. It's not suitable for anything long-running and cpu-intensive, but rather something where you need to execute on a regular interval. Clock UI updates are a perfect example.

Also Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.

[For more information use this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

If you want to use Timer for the background task then use the 
[**System.Threading.Timer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead of DispatcherTimer

[For more information use this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)